# Understanding Recursive Algebraic Types in Functional Programming

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

Hey I'm having some trouble understanding how Recursive Algebraic Types work and how to use them exactly.  For example, take the below RAT definition for the natural numbers:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

We're using a RAT here because the set of values needs to be infinite and I know the principle is to express each new value in terms of a previous one, but I don't understand how this forms the natural numbers.  Would someone mind clearing this up?  Thanks

Comment: Translate `Succ` with `1 +`. Every natural number is `1 + (1 + ( ... (1 + 0) ... ))` for a suitable number of operations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This states that:

- `Nat` is a type.
- `Zero` has type `Nat`. This represents the natural number 0.
- If `n` has type `Nat`, then `Succ n` has type `Nat`. This represents the natural number *n*+1.

So, for example, `Succ (Succ Zero)` represents 2, `Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))` represents 3, `Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))` represents 4, and so on. (This system of defining the natural numbers from 0 and successors is called the [Peano axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).)

In fact, `Zero` and `Succ` are just special kinds of functions *(constructors)* that are declared to create `Nat` values:

```
Zero :: Nat
Succ :: Nat -> Nat
```

The difference from regular functions is that you can take them apart with pattern-matching:

```
predecessor :: Nat -> Nat
predecessor Zero = Zero
predecessor (Succ n) = n
```

Nothing about this is special to recursive algebraic data types, of course, just algebraic data types; but the simple fact that an algebraic data type can have a value of the same type as one of its fields is what creates the recursion here.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear answer ehird!  So is the Succ constructor an inbuilt function representing n+1?  I was confused because I thought it was just declaring another possible value in the normal fashion.  If we have a number n, why do we want to represent the value n+1 i.e. the next value in the natural number sequence?  Aren't we just concerned with how we can express the value n?  Thanks for the pattern matching bit at the end - it was very useful!

Comment: No, it's not built-in; you could rename it to `Fnarf` and it'd be exactly the same. The idea is that we define this type, and assign each value of it a *meaning* as a natural number: we *represent* the data with the type. `Succ n` represents *n* + 1 because *n* already has to be represented by *another* `Nat`. If you have `Zero` (0), and you want 1, you have to use `Succ Zero`, to represent 0 + 1 = 1. If you have `Succ Zero` (1), and you want 2, you have to use `Succ (Succ Zero)`, to represent 1 + 1 = 2... and so on.

Comment: @user1058210 No, Succ is not built-in. It's just the name you gave to the constructor. You need a way to get from `n` to `n+1`, so you can represent any number. If the definition was just `data Nat = Zero`, you could only represent zero. Of course you could extend that to more numbers like `data Nat = Zero | One | Two`, but that approach only gives you a finite number of numbers. Using Succ you can just apply `Succ` to `Zero` `n` times to represent the number `n`.